# Dissapearing radiobutton on Windows Classic theme

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

my application has standard controls - textboxes, statics, and a few option buttons (radio buttons). When windows theme (XP) is set to "Classic", and user presses TAB on the form, radio buttons disappear, that is, they are not drawn. Dragging something over my window redraws them.

Any ideas?

Comment: radiobuttons are actually on frame border, and there is empty text on frame captions - there lies the problem, but how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you paste a sample program to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: resolved, frame had empty spaces as text, and windows misbehaves on classic theme in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote your own answer here Marin, so that the question no longer appears to have zero solutions, hope you dont mind :)

Quote:

> resolved, frame had empty spaces as text, and windows misbehaves on classic theme in this case. – Marin yesterday